# Синтаксические нормы

Tags: синтаксис

Исправьте ошибку, связанную с синтаксическими нормами

1. В жизни я не видывал человека, питавшего большое пристрастие к прочувствованным тостам и который умел бы их мастерски произносить.
2. Не надеясь ни на кого, ему пришлось пройти через долгие годы лишений.
3. Большинство населения России идут за демократическими лидерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ...,питавшего большое пристрастие к прочувствованным тостам и умевшего  их мастерски произносить.
2. ..., он прошел через долгие годы лишений.
3. Большинство населения России идёт ...

Answer (score 0):

В жизни я не видывал человека, питавшего большее пристрастие к прочувствованным тостам и  умевшего их мастерски произносить.
Не надеясь ни на кого,он проходил  через долгие годы лишений.
Большинство населения России идёт за демократическими лидера